# sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: stack depth limit exceeded

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I'm getting a `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError` error when I perform the following query:

```
    present_keys = self.engine.execute(
        _sql.select(
            [self.table.columns.qid, self.table.columns.did],
            _sql.tuple_(self.table.columns.qid, self.table.columns.did).in_(
                [(row['qid'], row['did']) for row in rows]
            )
        )
    ).fetchall()
```

The thing is, the query works for small amounts of rows like ~5k, but when I try to run it with around 50~100k I get this error.

I guess the query itself is a really bad way to do what I want. (I'm just checking which rows are already in the database, so I can separate the ones I need to insert from the ones I need to update).

What is my best option to solve this? Make a different query? Increase some kind of setting inside PostgreSQL/psycopg2?